# Chapter 3 Packages and patches virtual box problems

Tags: virtualbox, wget, lfs

I am making LFS I am curently at packages and patches. I ran command

```
pushd $LFS/sources
md5sum -c md5sums
popd
```

and it gave me

```
pushd $LFS/sources
md5sum -c md5sums
popd
/sources /sources
acl-2.3.1.tar.xz: OK
attr-2.5.1.tar.gz: OK
autoconf-2.71.tar.xz: OK
automake-1.16.4.tar.xz: OK
bash-5.1.8.tar.gz: OK
bc-5.0.0.tar.xz: OK
binutils-2.37.tar.xz: OK
bison-3.7.6.tar.xz: OK
bzip2-1.0.8.tar.gz: OK
check-0.15.2.tar.gz: OK
coreutils-8.32.tar.xz: OK
dbus-1.12.20.tar.gz: OK
dejagnu-1.6.3.tar.gz: OK
diffutils-3.8.tar.xz: OK
e2fsprogs-1.46.4.tar.gz: OK
elfutils-0.185.tar.bz2: OK
expat-2.4.1.tar.xz: OK
expect5.45.4.tar.gz: OK
file-5.40.tar.gz: OK
findutils-4.8.0.tar.xz: OK
flex-2.6.4.tar.gz: OK
gawk-5.1.0.tar.xz: OK
gcc-11.2.0.tar.xz: OK
gdbm-1.20.tar.gz: OK
gettext-0.21.tar.xz: OK
glibc-2.34.tar.xz: OK
gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz: OK
gperf-3.1.tar.gz: OK
grep-3.7.tar.xz: OK
groff-1.22.4.tar.gz: OK
grub-2.06.tar.xz: OK
gzip-1.10.tar.xz: OK
iana-etc-20210611.tar.gz: OK
inetutils-2.1.tar.xz: OK
intltool-0.51.0.tar.gz: OK
iproute2-5.13.0.tar.xz: OK
Jinja2-3.0.1.tar.gz: OK
kbd-2.4.0.tar.xz: OK
kmod-29.tar.xz: OK
less-590.tar.gz: OK
libcap-2.53.tar.xz: OK
libffi-3.4.2.tar.gz: OK
libpipeline-1.5.3.tar.gz: OK
libtool-2.4.6.tar.xz: OK
linux-5.13.12.tar.xz: OK
m4-1.4.19.tar.xz: OK
make-4.3.tar.gz: OK
man-db-2.9.4.tar.xz: FAILED
man-pages-5.13.tar.xz: OK
MarkupSafe-2.0.1.tar.gz: OK
meson-0.59.1.tar.gz: OK
mpc-1.2.1.tar.gz: OK
mpfr-4.1.0.tar.xz: OK
ncurses-6.2.tar.gz: FAILED
ninja-1.10.2.tar.gz: FAILED
openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz: OK
patch-2.7.6.tar.xz: OK
perl-5.34.0.tar.xz: OK
pkg-config-0.29.2.tar.gz: OK
procps-ng-3.3.17.tar.xz: OK
psmisc-23.4.tar.xz: OK
Python-3.9.6.tar.xz: OK
python-3.9.6-docs-html.tar.bz2: OK
readline-8.1.tar.gz: OK
sed-4.8.tar.xz: OK
shadow-4.9.tar.xz: OK
systemd-249.tar.gz: OK
systemd-man-pages-249.tar.xz: OK
tar-1.34.tar.xz: OK
tcl8.6.11-src.tar.gz: FAILED
tcl8.6.11-html.tar.gz: OK
texinfo-6.8.tar.xz: OK
tzdata2021a.tar.gz: OK
util-linux-2.37.2.tar.xz: OK
vim-8.2.3337.tar.gz: OK
XML-Parser-2.46.tar.gz: OK
xz-5.2.5.tar.xz: OK
zlib-1.2.11.tar.xz: OK
zstd-1.5.0.tar.gz: OK
binutils-2.37-upstream_fix-1.patch: OK
bzip2-1.0.8-install_docs-1.patch: OK
coreutils-8.32-i18n-1.patch: OK
glibc-2.34-fhs-1.patch: OK
kbd-2.4.0-backspace-1.patch: OK
perl-5.34.0-upstream_fixes-1.patch: OK
systemd-249-upstream_fixes-1.patch: OK
md5sum: WARNING: 4 computed checksums did NOT match
/sources
```

But I ran  `wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.37.tar.xz --no-check-certificate`

```
wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.11-src.tar.gz --no-check-certificate

 wget https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/archive/v1.10.2/ninja-1.10.2.tar.gz --no-check-certificate

wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.2.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
```

But the problem still lasts. How can I resolve this? Thank you for all your answers and advices.

Comment: That step is just to verify the integrity of the downloads and ensure you didn't accidentally download the wrong thing or malware. If you are confident that the archives you downloaded are legitimate, you can move on to the next step and ignore the warnings.

Comment: @jordanm Will it cause any big trouble if I keep it as it is and move on next steps? So I don't have to resolve these packages : ninja, ncurses, tcl and binutils? Of course they are legitimate it's all links to archives that are in official LFS Guide.

Comment: The md5 sums are there to protect against a man-in-the-middle attack, where you *think* you download from the official archives, but someone else redirects you to a malware site. So (1) think about the impact: if this is malware, what's the worst that can happen? If it's all a VM for learning purposes, probably not much. (2) Try to get both md5 sums and packages in a different way (and compare the exact versions), and see if you cannot figure out where the differences come from.